# limit number of times the file can be downloaded

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I am creating a website , which people can create their own video and can download it from my server.

I want to limit the download count to 10.

So What I am planning is to serve a download file via a php file and update the count of the file to database.If it reaches 10 downloads.I deny the download.

But I guess it consume more resource.Is there any other way possible in linux server  such as using htaccess or something like that ? So after a file is accessed 10 times it should be automatically deleted.

EDIT : its not users...any people can use this website for free.

Comment: Since you talk about users, I guess people need to be logged in to download stuff, so just keep track of which user is downloading which file, so create table with userid, fileeid and nr_times_downlaoded or smthing, and just keep track..

Comment: no I am sorry..its not users...anyone can download the file.

Comment: Then just instead of storing userid, track IP adresses? Not that accurate, but it mightb e worth a shot?

Comment: its not about restricting the file to single person...he can share link to any one too...but total download count should be 10

Comment: Then just keep track how many times a file has been downloaded in the database? (id, filename, nr_of_downloads, limit) ?

Comment: yea but Moax6629 answer is more good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to avoid DB queries for this you can apply a simple technique in filename to indicate remaining limit Like filename-10, filename-9 etc. But to use this approach u need to update the part after "-" on each download.

This could be one approach.

Comment: thats one clever idea :D

Comment: ahh wait,,,how can i find the filename again while downloading :p

Comment: in filename-10, file name will stay same, for searching and retrieving only the part before "-" will be used.

Comment: but can you tell me how to search filenames before hypens  ?I guess only looping and checking is possible ? If i set limit to 100 download it will be too much resource consuming than database..or Am i wrong ?

Comment: where are u searching the file from? from a database ?

Comment: @moax669 no...its generated on the fly and given to users.

Answer (score 0):

I one of the simplest solution,

in the user profile folder store the file in the file system and when the counter in the database reaches 10 then use `unlink()` method in php to delete that file.